# How car parts codes works?

Tags: maintenance, parts

Are the parts code universal or does each company have their own code?
Please provide brief answers, or if someone know any relevant site please share. That will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little vague. What are you really trying to find out? Compatibility between different manufacturers? Understanding the logic behind part numbers?

Comment: "does each company have their own code" Yes, aftermarket manufacturers use their own, some use codes from larger companies to be compatible. Auto manufacturers definitely have their own numbering system.

Answer (score 1):

Each manufacturer has their own and it gets interesting that an original part for a Jaguar appears to be made by Volvo - at least I read that on a forum post. I worked in parts for a bit and each main dealer, different makes, had different systems - at least then but I don't think that will have changed. They want their logo on the bag / box and won't like advertising someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: each **car** manufacturer will have it's own part numbering system that is completely different from other **car** manufacturer. However, **parts** manufacturers sometimes use the **car** manufacturer part number just so their part can be found and listed by suppliers, distributors and parts stores as a compatible replacement for an original part.

Comment: @thingan to be clear, not picking on you but highlighting an issue !  I query the use of the word "legit" - too many parts are sadly found to be inferior or incorrect or just a cheap copy while showing the 'correct' part number : I have to be very careful for my car some aftermarket parts suppliers will provide mondeo parts which look ok, but cause HUGE problems.

Comment: @SolarMike By legit, I meant "intended to be used with." I have the same issue with poor quality and cheap copies (Cardone and Doorman don't always fit what they're supposed to fit, for me). I'll see about rewording it.

Comment: Ok, but really didn't mean you to re-word it - apologies. Just wanted to highlight another issue, but perhaps that should be a post by itself...

Comment: @SolarMike Clarity for posterity! :D